# Convert Asp.Net MVC/ EF application to NoSQL application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nosql, ravendb

We are thinking about convert Asp.Net MVC/EF/SQL application to NoSQL application to improve development speed and application speed. It looks like there is mixed response on ravendb, I want to know if you have using NoSQL in a .Net environment , what you are using.

Also, our business still rely on SSRS to do reports, and it is important that we can still export data from NoSQL to SQL environment, what will you suggest to export data from NoSQL to SQL Server.

Thanks for you comments.

Comment: I am a huge follower and fan of RavenDB - but this question isn't a great fit for StackOverflow, as it will ultimately lead to flame wars between differing opinions.  If you would like a better response as to whether RavenDB is a good fit for your particular scenarios, please ask on the [RavenDB Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb).  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, we haven't decided which NoSQL db to go, and want to know the options out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents:

- RavenDB is a good document database. I'm using it in a .NET environment and it integrated nicely.
- Move to a NoSQL database only if your data makes sense in such a structure or the foreseen performance improvement is compelling enough. RavenDB is a document database so it works great with documents but it's much harder to work with relational data. You'll likely find that keeping relational data in a SQL database is more efficient from a development perspective, but perhaps you'll find better performance with a NoSQL database (probably not RavenDB) at the expense of some developer efficiency.
- Be open to a mix of SQL and NoSQL in your environment. For example you may find that your relational data fits best in SQL and your document data fits best in RavenDB. Or perhaps you'll want your document data in both places which would require some SQL-RavenDB syncing.

<strike>For exporting from RavenDB to SQL, check out RavenDB's [Index Replication Bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/1.0/server/bundles/index-replication).</strike> *Please see Matt's comment about the latest bundle to use.*

Comment: Index Replication Bundle is for RavenDB 1.0 and deprecated.  Current advise is to use the [SQL Replication Bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/extending/bundles/sql-replication), which is much more powerful and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You will find (open sourced) BrightStarDB the closest fit from a DBContext solution for entityframework, as for pulling data out you can export it either writing your own app/query/or its own query language. Got a few options there.

Check it out BrightStarDb.com